# Jquery .load() callback not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, asynccallback, popstate

Ive been struggling with this for hours now. I can't figure out why my .load() callback is not firing. Can anyone shed any light on this. Thanks for any help.

The load it's self works fine.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {

  var linkplus = ((event.state) + ' #container'); //contents

  if((event.state)==null){
    $("#maincontainer").load("index.php #container", "null" , function(){
        return false;
        //  why is this not working ???  //
        alert("contents loaded");
    });
  }else{
    $("#maincontainer").load(linkplus, function(){
        return false;
        $("#container").hide().delay(0).fadeIn(400);
        project_nav();
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

hm, doesn't look like your alert would be hit right?  You already return false before that.

Answer (score 1):

When you return from a function, you return

```
$("#maincontainer").load("index.php #container", "null" , function(){

    return false;  // YOU RETURNED HERE, NOTHING BELOW IS EXECUTED

    alert("contents loaded");

});
```

There's no need to return anything from `load()`

Answer (score 0):

Hey I tried removing the "return false" with no success.I think it's because .load() is asynchronous?

Anyway, I got it to work using ".get" instead of .load and then selecting the contents with a variable. Thanks for the replies.

```
    $.get( "index.php", function( data ) {
        var content = $(data).find('#container').html();
        $("#container").html(content);
        alert("contents loaded");
    });
```